# combinations of $n$ things taken $k$ at a time with $n < k$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

Usually on books one reads about combinations of $n$ things taken $k$ at a time (without repetition) as the binomial coefficient $$B(n,k)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$
and the dispositions of $n$ objects taken $k$ at a time as
$$D(n,k)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}.$$
The standing assumption is that $n \geq k.$ What happens if $k> n?$ Can we invert the role of $n$ and $k$ in this case? I mean taking combinations of $n$ things taken $k$ at a time (without repetition) ($k> n$) as taking combinations of $k$ "places" taken $n$ (objects) at a time and the same for dispositions, i.e. considering $$B(k,n), \quad D(k,n)?$$

Comment: Logically, it would mean nothing. You can't chose more objects than there actually are, However, according to the formula the result would just tend to 0, but there's no point considering this.

Comment: It is convenient to go for $B(n,k)=D(n,k)=0$ if $k\notin\{0,1,\dots,n\}$. Then e.g. the rule $B(n,k-1)+B(n,k)=B(n+1,k)$ in the Pascal triangle stays valid. Also it corresponds nicely with our thinking. How many subsets of $5$ elements has a set that has $3$ elements? Well, $0$ of course.

Comment: If $D(n,k) = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)$ then this is $0$ when $k >n$.  Similarly if $B(n,k)=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots1}$  is $0$  when $k >n$.  In both cases you get a multiplication by $0$.

Comment: I haven't seen the word "dispositions" used this way in English. Is this a translation?

Comment: In the two cases, we are talking about $k$ **distinct** objects, the first as a set, the second as an ordered tuple. So when $k>n,$ there are zero ways, so the values is $0.$

Comment: For cases where the $k$ elements are not necessarily distinct, you get $\binom{n+k-1}k$ multi-sets, and $n^k$ ordered $k$-tuples, and this is non-zero even when $k>n.$

Comment: I was thinking about allowing some places to be empty. So choosing all $n$ objects in $n$ places and the remaining $n-k$ places are allowed to be empty

Comment: yes I'm spanish, I probably mistaken the term @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  I suspect people may call these [Combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) and [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Other_uses_of_the_term_permutation) using $C(n,k)$ and $P(n,k)$

Comment: I don't follow the "some places might be empty" question in the prior comment. @carlos85

Answer (score 1):

We adopt the convention that $B(k,n)=D(k,n)=0$, whenever $0\le k< n$. The reasoning is that, since there you are trying to take more things than there are things available, the task is impossible, so there are zero ways to complete the task.

This actually agrees with the factorial formula, if you think a little creatively. For example, we would say
$$
B(2,3)\,``="\,\frac{2!}{3!\cdot (-1)!}
$$
Of course, $(-1)!$ is not well defined, using the classical definition of factorial. You can extend the domain of factorial using the Gamma function to include almost all complex numbers, via
$$
z!\stackrel{\text{def}}=\Gamma(z+1)
$$
Therefore, we could atttempt to define $B(2,3)$ as
$$
B(2,3)=\frac{\Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(4)\cdot \Gamma(0)}
$$
Still, the gamma function has an infinite singularity at $0$, so the above does not resolve our problem. Intuitively, you could say $(-1)!=\Gamma(0)``="\infty$, and dividing by infinity produces a zero, but we can be more precise than this.

Since $B(n,k)$ is defined whenever $(n,k)$ is approximately equal to $(2,3)$ in the complex plane, we can use the gamma definition for nearby values and take a limit. We define
$$
B(n,k)=\lim_{(z,w)\to (n,k)}\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\Gamma(w+1)\Gamma(z-w+1)}
$$
whenever this limit exists. Doing so, you indeed find $B(2,3)=0$. That is, the algebraic formula and the combinatorial interpretation agree with each other.